# Convert dataframe to an association matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame containing customer visits at different sites we have. For example:

```
df1 <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = 
'customer,site1,site2,site3
a.1,1,20,30
a.1,2,30,1
a.2,3,40,10
a.3,2,10,10
a.4,0,1,2')

df1
      customer site1 site2 site3
1      a.1     1    20    30
2      a.1     2    30     1
3      a.2     3    40    10
4      a.3     2    10    10
5      a.4     0     1     2
```

I would like to reshape the above into a form as follows:

```
sites   site1   site2   site3
site1   8        100    51
site2   100      101    53
site3   51        53    53
```

The above matrix shows in the diagonal the column sums for each site in df1. For values not in the diagonal, they show how many visits occured at a site, given another site was also visited. So, from the final matrix, 2nd row and 1st column show how many visits took place for site2, given visits to site1.

But much to my disappointment I am finding it hard to achieve this, after spending a day without progress. I know that if I create a matrix of the sites, I can add the diagonal entries by summing, but that I think is a quite poor way of solving this. I think I could use some elementary maths to do this, but would appreciate some help/pointers.

### Edit

Apologies, the question was incorrect. The correct output is as shown by @josilber.

```
#       site1 site2 site3
# site1     8     8     8
# site2   100   101   101
# site3    51    53    53
```

My idea originally was to find out any pattern between the 3 sites, in terms of visits. If a customer visits, site 1 and site 2, but not site 3, I had hoped to capture this in the form of a matrix.

Comment: I guess the 51 is the first row sum?  How did you get 100?

Comment: @akrun apologies for confusion. The 51 in final_matrix[3,1] is the sum of column site 3, as long as site1 is > 0. The idea is to sum visits to another site, given a particular site is also visited. So, in the final matrix, 3rd row and 1st column has 51, which is sum(30,1,10,10) but not 2 from df1. This is because 2 occurs when site1 is 0.

Comment: @akrun, yes, just updated the post. Thanks ever so much! Meanwhile, I will try to formulate a solution myself too...

Comment: I am not sure this would help as the conditions are not clear for me  `m1 <- toeplitz(colSums(subset(df1[-1], site1!=0)));  diag(m1) <- colSums(df1[-1]);  m1[2*row(m1)==col(m1)+1 & upper.tri(m1) ] <-  tail(diag(m1),1);  m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- m1[upper.tri(m1)]`

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the help, even though the question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating over the numeric columns of `df1`, you can limit to rows where that column in positive, taking the column sums:

```
cols <- paste0("site", 1:3)
sapply(cols, function(x) colSums(df1[df1[,x] != 0, cols]))
#       site1 site2 site3
# site1     8     8     8
# site2   100   101   101
# site3    51    53    53
```